# flutter bottom navigation bar icon not showing

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

When I am used `BottomNavigationBarItem`, I can't showing my navigation icons.

I am trying this code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:task_manager/style/style.dart';

BottomNavigationBar AppBottomNav(currentIndex, OnItemTapped) {
  return BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt),
        label: "New",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.access_time_rounded),
        label: "Progress",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outlined),
        label: "Completed",
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
        label: "Canceled",
      ),
    ],
    selectedItemColor: colorGreen,
    unselectedItemColor: colorLightGray,
    currentIndex: currentIndex,
    showSelectedLabels: true,
    showUnselectedLabels: true,
    onTap: OnItemTapped,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
  );
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `uses-material-design: true` in pubspec.yaml

[image: BottomNavigationBar With Icons]

Answer (score 0):

Like [Alejandro Cumpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2789300/alejandro-cumpa) said, you need to add `uses-material-design: true` in your `pubspec.yaml`.

You need to add this to the bottom:

```yaml
name: …
description: …

publish_to: …

version: …

environment:
  …

dependencies:
  …

dev_dependencies:
  …

flutter:
  …
  uses-material-design: true
```